# Importing Data and Devoting Their Names to Them

Tags: list-manipulation, import, string-manipulation, data

There are some files in a directory. I have used of *SetDiroctory* to access all of them.

```
SetDirectory["C:\\Users\\SE7EN\\Desktop\\mathematica\\test"];
```

I can visit all theirs contents with

```
filenames = FileNames[]
{"Ronaldo.txt", "Messi.txt", "Beckenbauer.txt", "Zeydane.txt"}
loaddata[filenumber_] := Import[Part[FileNames[], filenumber]]
```

For example:

```
loaddata[4]     2    8    7     13   77
```

These are contents of Zeydane file. But I want to have imported files with the respectively devoted names. For example, desired result after that process, (which I do not know how it can be done), be same as bellow:

```
Ronaldo={2,3,5,8,0,1}
Messi={21,2,45,6}
Beckenbauer={11,42,5,2,7,21}
Zeydane={2,8,7,13,77}
```

One way is: importing them separately, `Messi=Import{.....,'data'}`. But it is not the desired process, The desired process must be done automatically. Automatically importing data from directory and devoting their names in that directory to the imported list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `FileBaseName` is useful to remove file suffixes.

Comment: uh, and the leading stuff as well, of course ;-)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your comments and answer. Please let me check your propose to my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like Yves Klett's method a lot, and if you are making the kind of substitutions he illustrates it is the way to go.  However here is how to do just what you requested, as well as another alternative using "indexed objects."

```
Set @@ Append[ToHeldExpression @ FileBaseName @ #, Import @ #] & /@ filenames
```

(`ToHeldExpression` is a deprecated function but still entirely usable and handy.)

And now indexed objects with strings as keys:

```
(data[FileBaseName @ #] = Import[#]) & /@ filenames
```

This is used with e.g.:

```
data["Ronaldo"]
```

> ```
> {2,3,5,8,0,1}
> ```

```
data /@ {"Beckenbauer", "Zeydane"}
```

> ```
> {{11, 42, 5, 2, 7, 21}, {2, 8, 7, 13, 77}}
> ```

Comment: Blush :D Any particular reason not to use `ToExpression`?

Comment: @Yves I presume you mean in place of `ToHeldExpression` etc.?  Only that if those Symbols are already assigned, e.g. if you externally update the files then attempt to reload them, it will fail.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of generating hardcoded variables and cluttering your namespace, I would suggest you try this:

```
names = {"a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt"};
vals = {1, 2, 3};
vars = ToExpression[FileBaseName /@ names];
data=Thread[vars -> vals]
```

> {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}

This allows for comfortable further calculations together with `ReplaceAll` and similar and will empower your football algebra:

```
a*b*c/.data
```

> 6

Leaving the variable names in their string representation will work as well. More typing will be involved, but the process will be more robust with respect to name clashes (you will probably be safe with `Beckenbauer` though...)

```
names = {"a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt"};
vals = {1, 2, 3};
vars = FileBaseName /@ names;
data = Thread[vars -> vals]
"a"*"b"*"c" /. data
```

> {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3}
>
> 6