# Get the name of a time series while using Table

Tags: evaluation, string-manipulation, labeling, symbols

I saw a number of related questions to the one I'm about to post; they helped, but none of them solved my problem entirely.

[Get the name of a symbol passed to a function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15687/get-the-name-of-a-symbol-passed-to-a-function)

[Obtaining the name of a variable as a string](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32223/obtaining-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string)

The general question is how to get the name of something (a function, a list...). From the previous questions, I learned that you could use a function with the `HoldFirst` attribute:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[x_] := SymbolName[Unevaluated@x]
```

This function works well when it's input is directly the element of which you want to get the name. However, in my case, I have to use `Table[]` and I want to get the name of multiple time series. For example, I have three time series, `ts1`, `ts2` `ts3`. I then want to produce two list plots, both with `ts1` on the x axis and then respectively one that has `ts2` on the y axis and another that has `ts3` on the y axis. Here is the code I used:

```
Table[ 

ListPlot[ Transpose[{ts1["Values"],i["Values"]}]
,Frame->True
,FrameLabel->{"ts1",i}
]

 ,{i,{ts2,ts3}} ]
```

But the y axis labels, on both plots, are the time series objects, not their names. If I use the function `f[_x]` that I linked above, I get:

Table[

```
ListPlot[ Transpose[{ts1["Values"],i["Values"]}]
,Frame->True
,FrameLabel->{"ts1",f[i]}
]

 ,{i,{ts2,ts3}} ]
```

Then the y axis label is just "i"... So what I need is a function that evaluates `i` "just enough" (forget the imprecise formulation) so that it is replaced by, let's say, `ts2`, but then holds the form and convert it to a symbol. I do not know how to do that.

Here are three time series if you want to try and mess around with them:

```
ts1={{3686428800,2},{3686515200,2},{3686601600,1},{3686688000,1.4},{3686774400,1.9},{3686860800,1.8},{3687033600,1.7},{3687120000,1.5},{3687206400,2},{3687379200,2},{3687465600,2},{3687552000,2.2},{3687638400,1.7},{3687724800,1.7},{3687897600,1.7},{3687984000,1.7},{3688243200,2},{3688329600,2},{3688502400,1.7},{3688588800,2.3},{3688675200,1.7},{3688761600,1.7},{3688848000,1.7},{3689020800,1.7},{3689107200,2},{3689193600,1.7},{3689366400,2.4},{3689452800,1.7},{3689539200,0.5},{3689625600,2},{3689712000,1.7},{3689798400,1.7},{3689884800,1.7},{3689971200,1.7},{3690057600,2.1},{3690144000,1.7},{3690230400,2.1},{3690316800,3.4}}

ts2={{3686428800,7.7},{3686515200,12.3},{3686601600,9.5},{3686688000,3.7},{3686774400,5.7},{3686860800,5.1},{3687033600,8.3},{3687120000,8.3},{3687206400,6.1},{3687379200,4.3},{3687465600,5.9},{3687552000,5.8},{3687638400,7.5},{3687724800,3.9},{3687897600,5.9},{3687984000,7.6},{3688243200,8.6},{3688329600,4},{3688502400,6.1},{3688588800,5},{3688675200,10},{3688761600,10.6},{3688848000,7.5},{3689020800,7.2},{3689107200,11.3},{3689193600,10.3},{3689366400,9.2},{3689452800,10.2},{3689539200,8},{3689625600,8.3},{3689712000,7.3},{3689798400,7.7},{3689884800,7.9},{3689971200,7.3},{3690057600,9.3},{3690144000,11.9},{3690230400,13},{3690316800,9.8}}

ts3={{3686428800,0.364583},{3686515200,0.395833},{3686601600,0.604167},{3686688000,0.479167},{3686774400,0.458333},{3686860800,0.416667},{3687033600,0.375},{3687120000,0.416667},{3687206400,0.416667},{3687379200,0.40625},{3687465600,0.385417},{3687552000,0.395833},{3687638400,0.375},{3687724800,0.395833},{3687897600,0.416667},{3687984000,0.364583},{3688243200,0.375},{3688329600,0.333333},{3688502400,0.385417},{3688588800,0.375},{3688675200,0.375},{3688761600,0.354167},{3688848000,0.395833},{3689020800,0.416667},{3689107200,0.416667},{3689193600,0.375},{3689366400,0.458333},{3689452800,0.395833},{3689539200,0.395833},{3689625600,0.395833},{3689712000,0.364583},{3689798400,0.385417},{3689884800,0.375},{3689971200,0.354167},{3690057600,0.385417},{3690144000,0.375},{3690230400,0.520833},{3690316800,0.375}}
```

Comment: Related: [(32202)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32202/121) [(49107)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/49107/121), [(88892)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88892/121).  Possibly of interest though not really applicable: [(334)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/334/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Proposed alternatives

This is a matter of controlling evaluation.  You can do this with varying degrees of difficulty using things like [`HoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html), [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html), etc., or you can simply avoid the problem in the first place which is what I greatly prefer.

To do this you can separate the names from the data using [indexed objects](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html), Rules, or Associations.  Instead of defining `ts1 = TimeSeries[. . .]` you would write one of the following:

```
ts[1] = TimeSeries[. . .]

data["ts1"] = TimeSeries[. . .]

ts1[] = TimeSeries[. . .]

rules = {"ts1" -> TimeSeries[. . .], "ts2" -> TimeSeries[. . .]}

asc = <|"ts1" -> TimeSeries[. . .], "ts2" -> TimeSeries[. . .]|>
```

In each case you can freely pass around a reference (name) for the `TimeSeries` expression without it automatically evaluating to anything.

You would reference each of these in the respective manner:

```
Table[Labeled[ts[i], Row[{"ts", i}]], {i, 1, 3}]

Table[Labeled[data[name], name], {name, {"ts1", "ts2", "ts3"}}]

Table[Labeled[ts[], ts], {ts, {ts1, ts2, ts3}}]

Table[Labeled[name /. rules, name], {name, {"ts1", "ts2", "ts3"}}]

Table[Labeled[asc[name], name], {name, {"ts1", "ts2", "ts3"}}]
```

#### Self-contained examples

Let me see if I can provide a concrete example using your data.

```
t = {3686428800, 3686515200, 3686601600, 3686688000, 3686774400, 3686860800, \
3687033600, 3687120000, 3687206400, 3687379200, 3687465600, 3687552000, 3687638400, \
3687724800, 3687897600, 3687984000, 3688243200, 3688329600, 3688502400, 3688588800, \
3688675200, 3688761600, 3688848000, 3689020800, 3689107200, 3689193600, 3689366400, \
3689452800, 3689539200, 3689625600, 3689712000, 3689798400, 3689884800, 3689971200, \
3690057600, 3690144000, 3690230400, 3690316800};

valeurs = {{2,2,1,1.4,1.9,1.8,1.7,1.5,2,2,2,2.2,1.7,1.7,1.7,1.7,2,2,1.7,2.3,1.7,1.7,1.7,1.7,2,1.7,2.4,1.7,0.5,2,1.7,1.7,1.7,1.7,2.1,1.7,2.1,3.4},
{7.7,12.3,9.5,3.7,5.7,5.1,8.3,8.3,6.1,4.3,5.9,5.8,7.5,3.9,5.9,7.6,8.6,4,6.1,5,10,10.6,7.5,7.2,11.3,10.3,9.2,10.2,8,8.3,7.3,7.7,7.9,7.3,9.3,11.9,13,9.8},
{0.364583,0.395833,0.604167,0.479167,0.458333,0.416667,0.375,0.416667,0.416667,0.40625,0.385417,0.395833,0.375,0.395833,0.416667,0.364583,0.375,0.333333,0.385417,0.375,0.375,0.354167,0.395833,0.416667,0.416667,0.375,0.458333,0.395833,0.395833,0.395833,0.364583,0.385417,0.375,0.354167,0.385417,0.375,0.520833,0.375}};

nomsVariables = {ts1, ts2, ts3};
```

Now:

```
MapThread[(#1[] = TimeSeries[#2, {t}]) &, {nomsVariables, valeurs}];
```

Access and labeling of various time series as an illusration:

```
Labeled[#[], #] & /@ nomsVariables
```

If `nomsVariables` is a list of Strings rather than Symbols I recommend that you use the second, fourth or fifth forms shown earlier so as to avoid the need to convert to Symbols:

```
nomsVariables = {"ts1", "ts2", "ts3"};

MapThread[(data[#1] = TimeSeries[#2, {t}]) &, {nomsVariables, valeurs}]

Labeled[data[#], #] & /@ nomsVariables
```

#### The question at face value

To leave no stone unturned I should address the actual question as asked rather than only proposing an alternative.  You can [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) the individual Symbols in the `Table` and then [`ReleaseHold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold.html) that expression when you need it to resolve to the `TimeSeries`:

```
Table[ListPlot[Transpose[{ts1["Values"], ReleaseHold[i]["Values"]}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"ts1", i}], {i, {HoldForm[ts2], HoldForm[ts3]}}]
```

This works for the example given but it introduces other question like how to create the list `{HoldForm[ts2], HoldForm[ts3]}` apart from typing it in.  Typically you would start with an expression of held Symbols *before* they (`ts2`, `ts3`, etc.) are assigned values.  Another question exists that addresses the use of this form to some degree: [Elegant manipulation of the variables list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/121)  Nevertheless IMHO this should not be used commonly but rather as a special purpose tool.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying out what you proposed by using the indexed objects `ts1[]`. It is indeed much simpler than messing around with the evaluation. However, I do have another question related to these indexed objects. As I dont have 3, but around 50 times series to define, I'm trying to define them as a bunch, but I get the error message `Set::write: Tag Map in (#1[]&)/@{liquide,travail} is Protected.`. Here is what I tried: `Map[#[] &, Symbol /@ nomsVariables[[;; 2]]] = 
 Map[TimeSeries[#, {t}] &, valeurs[[;; 2]], {1}]`.

Comment: Where `nomsVariables` contains the names of all the variables, `t` contains the different dates and where `valeurs` contains the different variables (one sublist per variable).

Comment: Never mind, I just added an `Evaluate`...: `Evaluate[Map[#[] &, Symbol /@ nomsVariables[[;; 2]]]] = Map[TimeSeries[#, {t}] &, valeurs[[;; 2]], {1}]`.

Comment: @EBassal give me a minute; I am looking at your example.  If you've found a solution in the mean time that's fine.

Comment: well I found a workaround, but if you have another idea, I'm all ears!

Comment: @EBassal Please see my update.  I hope you find the examples useful, but if not it seems you found what you need.  Thanks for the Accept.

Comment: Thanks again, your answer really is packed with information.

Comment: @EBassal Happy to help. :-)